# Post not being recieved from checkbox form php

Tags: php, html, forms, post, checkbox

I'm posting from the HTML code shown in this jsfiddle to the PHP page for which the code is below. The issue is that the array `$_POST['selectedpost']` isn't being received. That's the array containing which checkboxes were ticked. In the js fiddle I added in an example row to the table containing the checkboxes as normally these are generated using PHP and SQL.

```
<?php
include "connect2.php";

if (isset($_POST['selectedpost'])) {
$postschecked = $_POST['selectedpost'];
$length = count($postschecked);
}
else{
returnpage();
}

if (isset($_POST['deleteposts'])) {
foreach($postschecked as $post_id){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id='$post_id'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
returnpage();
}

if (isset($_POST['passposts'])) {
foreach($postschecked as $post_id){
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET moderation=1 WHERE post_id='$post_id'";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
returnpage();
}

if (isset($_POST['editpost'])) {
if ($lenght==1){
    foreach($postschecked as $post_id){
        header("location:editpost.php?post_id=$post_id");
    }
}
else{
    returnpage();
}
}

if (isset($_POST['returnpost'])) {
if (isset($_POST['reasonreturned'])) {

    foreach($postschecked as $post_id){

        $sql = "SELECT description FROM posts WHERE post_id='$post_id'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $array = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $array[] = $row; }
        $description = "".$array[0][0];

        $description = $description . "<br/><br/><span style='color:red;font-size:18px;'>" . $_POST['reasonreturned'] . "</span>";

        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET description='$description' WHERE post_id='$post_id'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
foreach($postschecked as $post_id){
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET moderation=3 WHERE post_id='$post_id'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
}
returnpage();
}

if ($length){
returnpage();
}

function returnpage(){
//header("location:moderate.php");
}
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3A6az/2/

Also extra note, I am aware as to how un-efficient my code is in places and I'm also aware to the fact I should drop mysql and move to something like mysqli. Thank's for any help given

Comment: Array, what array? You're using an input `<input type='checkbox' name='selectedpost' value='404'></input>` plus you don't need `</input>` If anything you shouldn't be using `value='404'` unless that's what you want to pass as a "value". You probably meant to use use multiple checkboxes and using `name='selectedpost[]'`

Comment: The value 404 was an example I put in, thats all generated by itself normally. Good point about the /input, thanks, i forgot about that. Also when checkbox's are posted in a form I thought they passed an array?

Comment: They would if your checkboxes were named `name='selectedpost[]'` with the `[]` as in `<input type='checkbox' name='selectedpost[]'>`

Comment: I would like to point out though, that switching to `mysqli_*` functions would be most beneficial. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Using prepared statements or PDO would be even better in order to protect yourself. Here is a guide on how to prevent SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/

Comment: And I found a typo which may give you trouble `if ($lenght==1){` you have the word `$length` in your code as well. Change it to `if ($length==1){`

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- , spotted that myself though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than 1 checkbox you need to use

```
name='selectedpost[]'
```

It will then be available to you with `$_POST['selectedpost'];` as an array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that completely passed my mind! Ill try that

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it :) I knew It was going to be something stupidly simple, ill tick this when it allows me

Comment: Glad I could help! I love green arrows so please do! :)

Comment: [Isn't that what I said?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391365/post-not-being-recieved-from-checkbox-form-php#comment32264315_21391365) @Shard

Comment: Just realised no, its not. He posted first I'm afraid, you just edited your first comment

Answer (score 2):

You're using an unbracketed input `<input type='checkbox' name='selectedpost' value='404'></input>` plus you don't need `</input>` <(FYI)

If anything you shouldn't be using `value='404'` unless that's what you want to pass as a "value".

You probably meant to use multiple checkboxes and using `name='selectedpost[]'`

I.e.:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='selectedpost[]'>
```

Using square brackets `[]` are treated as an array.

---

**Footnotes:**

I would like to point out though, that switching to `mysqli_*` functions would be most beneficial. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Using [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would be even better in order to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Here is a guide on how to prevent SQL injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

---

**N.B.:** I also found a typo which may give you trouble `if ($lenght==1){`

You have the word `$length` in your code as well. Change it to `if ($length==1){`

Comment: Upvote for pointing out /input but I'm afraid you were beaten to it

Comment: It's ok (fair is fair) ;-) . I appreciate the upvote and glad this was resolved. @Shard

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've upvoted your answer as well just to be fair :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Awesome! I wonder if people actually partner up here and just vote up each other's answers all day long...lol

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go as far a "voting up all day" lol! But credit is given where credit is due, and yours definitely was worthy of it :) @Yani

Comment: Thank you kind sir @Fred-ii- :) It was just the caffeine that made me type faster lol

Comment: Haha, mine wasn't quite ready yet. Had to wait for the water to boil ;-) @Yani